# CSS challenges when leveraging 'Swiper' JS Library for my prototype

Tags: javascript, css, swiper.js

I'm prototyping in HTML/JS/CSS, trying to build the following:

[image: image color extraction]

Unfortunately, I'm struggling with the CSS part. Below you can find a minimal implementation which is fully functional, but contains 4 issues:

1. When scrolling from slide 1 --> slide 19, I am only able to scroll halfway through slide 19. Howcome? I'd like to see slide 19 entirely.
2. I uploaded a 512x512 image, which results in a 285x285 image when in memory. Howcome?
3. I am not able to use 'display: inline' to bring both divs: `<div class="swiper-slide0">First Color</div>` and `<div class="swiper-container">` on one line (cfr. visualization of end result). Howcome?
4. 'Swiper' JS Library allows to set 'slidesPerView' (e.g. equal to 5), but once applied, it remains like that, regardless of screen dimensions.

   - I'd like to set a blockWidth/blockHeight, based on the device’s screenWidth/screenHeight which is always applied within the range of readability/usability (e.g. when the screen is 1127px wide, a maximum number of blocks should be shown, be it 5, 6, 7 or maybe only 4). Hence I want to dynamically set blockWidth/blockHeight instead of having to enter slidesPerView which now results in the fact that blockWidth/blockHeight are changed when the screen is resized to adhere to slidesPerView = 5.
   - Current solution: I changed "width: 100%;" in '.swiper-container' to "width: 285px;". The JS then automatically assigns the width of the elements to 55px. I then use this outcome to manually set the size of other elements. Expected outcome: automated alternative in native JavaScript/CSS

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

  <title>Prototyping</title>

  <!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->

  <!-- Override/Add -->
  <style id="color_thief-js">

    .image-section {
        margin-bottom: 80px;
    }

    .image-wrap {
        position: relative;
        line-height: 1em;
        min-height: 240px;
        background-color: var(--hover-bg-color);
        border-radius: var(--border-radius-xl);
    }

    .target-image {
        border-radius: var(--border-radius-xl);
        transition: border-radius 0.2s 0.3s;
    }

    .target-image {
        display: block;
        width: 20%;
        border-radius: var(--border-radius-xl) var(--border-radius-xl) 0 0;
    }

  </style>

  <!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.1/css/swiper.css">

  <!-- Override/Add -->
  <style id="swiper-js">

    .swiper-container {
      width: 285px;*/
      /*width: 100%;*/
      /*height: 100%;*/
    }

    .swiper-slide {
      height: 55px;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 10px;
      font-weight: 400;
      line-height: 1.5;
      color: #212529;
      background: #fff;
      /* Center slide text vertically */
      align-items: center;
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }

    .swiper-slide0 {
      width: 55px;
      height: 55px;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 10px;
      font-weight: 400;
      line-height: 1.5;
      color: #212529;
      background: #fff;
      border: 2px solid black;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }
  </style>

  <style id="custom">

  div.first-container {
    display:inline;
  }

  </style>

  <!-- Link Swiper's JS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.1/js/swiper.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<script>

      var dcolor;
      var colorp;
      var base64String1;
      var base64String2;
      var base64String3;

      window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        document.getElementById('sf_0').addEventListener('change', function() {
          if (document.getElementById('sf_0').files[0]) {
              console.log("--- Image #1 ---");
              //console.log(document.getElementById('image_0'));
              var img1 = document.getElementById('image_0');
              var reader = new FileReader();
              reader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById('sf_0').files[0]);
              reader.onload = function () {
                base64String1 = reader.result;
                img1.src = base64String1;
                //console.log(img1.src);
                img1.id = document.getElementById('image_0').id;
                //console.log(img1.id);
                //extractColors(img1.id, 1);
              };
              reader.onerror = function (error) {
                console.log('Error: ', error);
              };

          }
        });
      });

</script>

<div class="image-section ">
  <div class="image-wrap"><input class="source-file" id="sf_0" type='file' /><br><img class="target-image" id="image_0" alt="image_0" src="#"></div>
  <div class="first-container">
      <div class="swiper-slide0">First Color</div>
      <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 11</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 12</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 13</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 14</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 15</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 16</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 17</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 18</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 19</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="second-container">
      <div class="swiper-slide0">Second Color</div>
      <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 11</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 12</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 13</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 14</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 15</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 16</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 17</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 18</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 19</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="third-container">
      <div class="swiper-slide0">Third Color</div>
      <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 11</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 12</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 13</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 14</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 15</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 16</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 17</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 18</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 19</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Initialize Swiper -->
  <script>
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      slidesPerView: 5,
      spaceBetween: 2.5,
      freeMode: true,
      //loop: true,
      simulateTouch: true,
    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: Also, posting a multipart question decreases the chance of a (quick) answer. I'll have a look at it, but honestly the extend of the issues deters me a bit...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. This is caused by the borders you have given to the slid elements. These mess up the way `Swiper` calculates the widths and how far it has to allow scrolling. Set `box-sizing: border-box` on all the elements inside the swiper to handle this.
2. I wasn't able to find anything regarding this in your code. You're not displaying/logging the image dimensions anywhere. Or maybe it's just not clear what you mean by "when in memory"
3. The `Swiper` default CSS sets `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto`. You have to override this to remove the margin. I'd also recommend aligning the row items using `display: flex`.
4. In order to have fixed width slides, set `slidesPerView: 'auto'` in the `Swiper` configuration and set a fixed `width`/`height` for your `.swiper-slide` elements that you can even change via CSS media query breakpoints. The swiper will automatically adapt on resize. (Click the "Full page" link below the Stack Snippet after running it and resize your browser window below 700px width for a demonstration.)

   However, this caused the right border of the last slide in each swiper to be cut off, even when scrolling as far to the right as possible. I fixed this by adding `margin-right: 1px` to each `.swiper-slide:last-child`.

   You can also use the `breakpoints` parameter to change `Swiper` options according to breakpoints that you can define. [See the official docs](https://swiperjs.com/api/#parameters).

I've left your style tags in the HTML part of the snippet and added my styles in the CSS part.

```js
var dcolor;
var colorp;
var base64String1;
var base64String2;
var base64String3;

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  document.getElementById('sf_0').addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (document.getElementById('sf_0').files[0]) {
      console.log("--- Image #1 ---");
      //console.log(document.getElementById('image_0'));
      var img1 = document.getElementById('image_0');
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById('sf_0').files[0]);
      reader.onload = function() {
        base64String1 = reader.result;
        img1.src = base64String1;
        //console.log(img1.src);
        img1.id = document.getElementById('image_0').id;
        //console.log(img1.id);
        //extractColors(img1.id, 1);
      };
      reader.onerror = function(error) {
        console.log('Error: ', error);
      };

    }
  });
});

var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  slidesPerView: 'auto',
  spaceBetween: 2,
  freeMode: true,
  //loop: true,
  simulateTouch: true
});
```

```css
.swiper-wrapper *,
.swiper-slide0 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.first-container,
.second-container,
.third-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 2.5px;
}

.swiper-container {
  margin: 0 !important;
  width: auto !important;
}

.swiper-slide0 {
  margin-right: 2.5px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.swiper-slide {
  width: 55px !important;
}

.swiper-slide:last-child {
  margin-right: 1px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .swiper-slide,
  .swiper-slide0 {
    width: 100px !important;
    height: 100px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<style id="color_thief-js">
  .image-section {
    margin-bottom: 80px;
  }
  
  .image-wrap {
    position: relative;
    line-height: 1em;
    /*min-height: 240px;*/
    background-color: var(--hover-bg-color);
    border-radius: var(--border-radius-xl);
  }
  
  .target-image {
    border-radius: var(--border-radius-xl);
    transition: border-radius 0.2s 0.3s;
  }
  
  .target-image {
    display: block;
    width: 20%;
    border-radius: var(--border-radius-xl) var(--border-radius-xl) 0 0;
  }
</style>

<!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.1/css/swiper.css">

<!-- Override/Add -->
<style id="swiper-js">
  .swiper-container {
    width: 285px;
  }
  
  .swiper-slide {
    height: 55px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #212529;
    background: #fff;
    /* Center slide text vertically */
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  
  .swiper-slide0 {
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #212529;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
</style>

<!-- Link Swiper's JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.1/js/swiper.js"></script>

<div class="image-section ">
  <div class="image-wrap"><input class="source-file" id="sf_0" type='file' /><br><img class="target-image" id="image_0" alt="image_0" src="#"></div>
  <div class="first-container">
    <div class="swiper-slide0">First Color</div>
    <div class="swiper-container">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 11</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 12</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 13</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 14</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 15</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 16</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 17</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 18</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="inner">Slide 19</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="second-container">
    <div class="swiper-slide0">Second Color</div>
    <div class="swiper-container">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 11</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 12</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 13</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 14</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 15</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 16</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 17</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 18</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 19</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="third-container">
    <div class="swiper-slide0">Third Color</div>
    <div class="swiper-container">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 11</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 12</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 13</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 14</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 15</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 16</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 17</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 18</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 19</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @constantin. Thanks for the effort put into this. Much appreciated! What I meant with question #2 is the following: when uploading a 512x512 image, `img#image_0.target-image` for example is assigned dimensions 284.8x284.8. I don't understand why its dimensions are reduced when displaying it through HTML. Hence I began playing with `.target image width: X%` For the record: the reason I referred to it as 'in memory' is because I didn't store this image in a database after upload.

Comment: I guess that's because of `.target-image { width: 20%; }`